# Kinect with Beagleboard

Tags: ros, kinect, beagleboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can Kinect run on Beagleboard using ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10478/kinect-with-beagleboard/) by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2011-07-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Yes](http://answers.ros.org/question/130/openni-compilation-error-diamondback-version?answer=296#296)

---

Originally posted by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) with karma: 482 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't tried it myself, but I think that the BeagleBoard is not powerful enough to keep up with the Kinect data rate.  I've heard of a few people having gotten the Kinect working on the beefier PandaBoard.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1